# Video Track Element only triggers load event on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Get track example</h1>

<video controls>
    <source src="media/test.mp4" />
    <track id="entrack" label="English subtitles" kind="captions" src="media/test-en.vtt" srclang="en" default />
</video>
<div style="display:block; overflow:auto; height:200px; width:650px; border: 1px solid;" id="display"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("entrack").addEventListener("load", function () {
    var myTrack = this.track; // get text track from track element          
    var myCues = myTrack.cues; // get list of cues                    
    for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
        // append track label
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += (myCues[i].getCueAsHTML().textContent + "<br/>");
    }
});
```

I tried to make this page with an `addEventListener()`. When the track was loaded, cues list would be displayed on a "div" element.

But I got into trouble, it only worked in Chrome while other browsers did't.

No error occurred.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAML2/)

**Edited:** If i have a button and listen for click event on it. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var myTrack = document.getElementById("entrack").track; // get text track from track element          
    var myCues = myTrack.cues;   // get list of cues                    
    for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
        // append track label
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += (myCues[i].getCueAsHTML().textContent + "<br/>");  
    }
}, false);
```

It worked on Firefox.

So... what is the difference between 'click' and 'load' event?

Comment: First thing I'd do is step through with Firefox / IE's debugger

Comment: Could you provide us a jsfiddle or something to test ?

Comment: The jsfiddle example doesn't work. It should use a real video and track file.

Comment: @João Mosmann: You can take caption and video from [this](https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-with-captions)

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because you didn't give the `addEventListener` function the third argument, which is either `true` or `false`, meaning "use capture" or not.

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("entrack").addEventListener("load", function() {
        var myTrack = this.track; // get text track from track element          
        var myCues = myTrack.cues;   // get list of cues                    
        for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
            // append track label
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += (myCues[i].getCueAsHTML().textContent + "<br/>");  
        }
    }, false); // here it is
```

Comment: It's worth trying but the third argument is *optional* in modern browsers

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried this... but nothing changed.

Comment: Provide me a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), for all I can see here the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the track already loaded. So you wait for something, that already happened. Or because you are using a buggy version of Firefox, which had a typo in the load event name and called it [loaded instead of load](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=882677#c27). Here is a simple pattern to get this right:

```
var myTrack = document.getElementById("entrack");
var myTrackListener = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 2){
        myTrack.removeEventListener('load', myTrackListener);
        myTrack.removeEventListener('loaded', myTrackListener);
        //start to do something
    }
};

myTrack.addEventListener('load', myTrackListener);
myTrack.addEventListener('loaded', myTrackListener);
myTrackListener.call(myTrack);
```

The following [demo](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/mediaelement/track-demo.html) also uses this pattern, here is the [sourcecode](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/track.js#L118-144). You might want to use [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#Media-track), which not only polyfills track element, but also fixes some browser bugs/issues ;-).

Answer (score 1):

In my case be able to trigger `load` event, I'm just set the mode of the track element.

I've used `track.mode = 'hidden'` or you can set `show` depends on requirement.

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

I searched about this issue and found some information. But, by my testings, its not possible because Firefox and the other browser didn't implemented the track tag completely.

Look at the MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTrackElement

There is a property of the TrackElement called readyState. It should tell you whether it is loading, loaded, or error.

In chrome, the following code returned 2. That means, it's loaded

```
document.getElementById("entrack")
```

But in firefox, the same code returns undefined. So, it means that firefox didn't implemented even the readyState property.

I suggest you to listen to the video tag load event. Or, even better, as a workaround. Instead of listening to the track load event, you could do a AJAX request to the track file, and in the callback, it will ensure you that the file exists and is loaded, so you can run your code.

But, there is another problem. If the browser does not support the track element, even if you use some workaround for the load event problem. Your code will not work, because you're using the Javascript API for tracks.

You can check whether the browser supports the track feature with the code below.

```
var supportsTrack = !!document.createElement('track').track;
if(supportsTrack) {
    // Do your job here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to guarantee `load` events are fired and `readyState` is set correctly you need to set the `track.mode` to `"showing"` eg:

`myTrack.mode = "showing"`

Otherwise the browser will not fire events.

See here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/mode#usage_notes

Answer (score -1):

You have to use attachEvent in IE versions prior to IE9. Check whether addEventListener is defined before using attachEvent.

```
var onTrack = document.getElementById("entrack");
if (onTrack.addEventListener) {
    onTrack.addEventListener("load", loadTrack, false);
}
else {
    onTrack.attachEvent("onload", loadTrack);
}

function loadTrack() {
    var myTrack = this.track; // get text track from track element          
    var myCues = myTrack.cues; // get list of cues                    
    for (var i = 0; i < myCues.length; i++) {
        // append track label
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += (myCues[i].getCueAsHTML().textContent + "<br/>");
    }
}
```